# How to compare hashed password from 2 servlets using jBCrypt

Tags: java, jbcrypt

I'm having problems on **how and where** to compare the password that I hashed on my registration servlet and the one that i hashed on my Login. servlet.

Hoping you guys could help me. Thanks.
login servlet:

```
String password = request.getParameter("pword");
String haspw = BCrypt.hashpw(password, salt);

/* if username and password match*/
UserIO io = new UserIO();

authenticate = io.LogAccount(username, haspw);
if (authenticate == true) {
    uri = "Homepage.jsp";
    session.setAttribute("active", username);
} else {
    uri = "/WEB-INF/jsp/error.jsp";
}
RequestDispatcher rd = request.getRequestDispatcher(uri);
rd.forward(request, response);
out.close();
```

UserIO

```
if (registered_name.isEmpty() ||registered_pass.isEmpty()) { //registered_name.equals(username) && registered_pass.equals(password)
    //uri = "Homepage.jsp";
    hasInfo = false;
} else if (registered_name.equals(username) && registered_pass.equals(password)) {
hasInfo = true;
}
```

Register Servlet

```
String pword = request.getParameter("pword");
    String hashed = BCrypt.hashpw(pword, salt);
```

Answer (score 1):

Use method `checkpw`:

```
BCrypt.checkpw(pword, salt);
```

This return a boolean in comparation.

Comment: Hi! Thanks for that. Which servlet should I compare it to? the Login servlet or register servlet?

Comment: Variable `pword` must be the string password filled in form login. After your edit I thinkg should be `password`